# How to custom push notification notice?

Tags: ios, push-notification

How to  custom push notification button for when presented with the option to select to "Allow" or "Don't allow" push notification? Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't customise the alert displayed that asks the user whether to Allow push notifications or not.

What some apps do is show an alert or image explaining what the push notifications are for, and when you press allow it shows the system Allow/Don't Allow alert.